# how to detect encoding of html FileReader?

Tags: jquery, encoding, filereader

txt file maybe utf8/GB2312,.... but if upload to my server, i got ascii only. how to detect file encoding, so i can set in readAsText()?

```
$("#fileinput").change(function(evt){
  if (!checkSupport())return; 
  var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
  if (!f) return;
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.onload = function(evt){   //file loaded successfuly
    g_fname=f.name;
    g_contents = evt.target.result;
    curpage.val(0);
    read_article();
  }
  r.readAsText(f,'GB2312');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

#### As of 2021 I think the easiest solution is to use [detect-file-encoding-and-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language)!

You can simply load it via the `<script>` tag:

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/detect-file-encoding-and-language/umd/language-encoding.min.js"></script>
```

**From the documentation:**

```html
// index.html
<body>
  <input type="file" id="my-input-field" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/detect-file-encoding-and-language/umd/language-encoding.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
// app.js
document.getElementById("my-input-field").addEventListener("change", inputHandler);
function inputHandler(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    languageEncoding(file).then(fileInfo => console.log(fileInfo));
    // Possible result: { language: english, encoding: UTF-8, confidence: { language: 0.97, encoding: 1 } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but since it is unanswered, I'd like to throw this out there to anyone who might be interested:

You should check out this library [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js)

They also have a working [demo](http://polygonplanet.github.io/encoding.js/tests/detect-file-encoding.html). I would suggest you first try it out with the files that you'll typically work with to see if it detects the encoding correctly and then use the library in your project.