# How to guess the encoding when using FileReader.readAsText() in frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I'm working on a project that uses `FileReader.readAsText()` and chances are high that users all over the world may use different encoding rather than "UTF-8", gb2312, big5, etc.
To prevent strange symbols resulted from decoding error, I use this:

reader.readAsText(file, “gb2312”);

But not everyone use that encoding.
Is there a better solution that works for all?
Well in python, I can use chardet.

Comment: I found a solution on another thread. Maybe this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66839583/11141834

Comment: So there's not a native way to do so?